# How would I troubleshoot a faulty GE electric oven?

Tags: repair, appliances, oven

When in bake mode the bake element will start to function by heating up, but after a brief time, there will be 2 audible clicks and it will shut off well before reaching the designated temp. It basically short cycles and will repeat without the oven ever getting warm.

Comment: the model# would be helpfull. many of these ovens have a control board with relays that turn the bake elements on. the relay contacts fail some times wiping out the board. with more info we may be able to even find part #'s

Comment: Note - the broiler works just fine. It is just the bake function.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the element, to test it you would need an ohm meter. here is a link to the repair clinic with parts and additional [testing videos](http://www.repairclinic.com/vwo7/Shop-For-Parts/a13b3d615043/Model-JBP24BH2WH-GE-Range-Stove-Oven-Parts)